# Activate the app on volume up/down/home button long press

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a requirement to activate the application on long press of home/volume up/down key while the device is regardless of locked or unlocked mode. Can anyone suggest me how this can be accomplished? Below is example scenarios:

Device is locked. I press 3 seconds on volume up button to activate the app.

Device is unlocked. I press 3 seconds on volume up button to activate the app.

Comment: Have you got a solution ..? I have a similar requirement .

Comment: No luck, I did not get solution yet.